# How do I invalidate a table in Oracle 11g on purpose?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, invalidation

I'm writing a small query to find invalid tables in Oracle :

```
select * from user_tables where status != 'VALID'
```

For testing, I thought it would be good to create a table and invalidate it on purpose. Is there a way to do this?

Invalidating a view is easy, just drop one of the underlying tables.

Any hint welcome.

Comment: You won't see status **INVALID** in **`user_tables`**, however, you would see that in **`[USER|ALL|DBA]_OBJECTS`** view.

Comment: It's easy to invalidate an index or a database type. Tables can be invalided only under special conditions. Your question does not make much sense.

Comment: @ibre5041 it does make sense, as it's not easy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see status **INVALID** in **`user_tables`**, however, you would see that in **`[USER|ALL|DBA]_OBJECTS`** view.

One simple way is to create the table using an **object type**, and force the object type **attribute** to **invalidate**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mytype AS OBJECT(col1 VARCHAR2(10))
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(col1 NUMBER,col2 mytype)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM user_objects WHERE object_name='T'
  2  /

OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS
----------- ----------------------- -----------
T           TABLE                   VALID

SQL>
```

So, the table is now in **VALID status**. Let's make it **INVALID**:

```
SQL> ALTER TYPE mytype ADD ATTRIBUTE col2 NUMBER INVALIDATE
  2  /

Type altered.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT object_name, object_type, status FROM user_objects WHERE object_name='T'
  2  /

OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS
----------- ----------------------- -----------
T           TABLE                   INVALID

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question but I want to point on something for future readers, the opposit of valid in the status user_tables is `UNUSABLE` so if you want to make a table `UNUSABLE`,A  DROP TABLE operation failed from [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2117.htm#i1592091)

> If a previous DROP TABLE operation failed, indicates whether the table
>   is unusable (UNUSABLE) or valid (VALID)

As for the type `INVALID` in user_objects its mainly related to `views/package/procedure` however lalit kumar gave a good example where a table is invalid.